# How to start and stop application pool in IIS using powershell script

Tags: .net, powershell, iis

I want to start and stop application pool in IIS using powershell script. I had try to write the script but i didn't get this.

Answer (score 37):

You can use this

**if your use (PowerShell 2.0) import WebAdministration module**

```
import-module WebAdministration
```

Please check the state of the application pool before. 
If the application pool is already stopped you get an exception.

**Stop application pool:**

```
$applicationPoolName = 'DefaultAppPool'

if((Get-WebAppPoolState -Name $applicationPoolName).Value -ne 'Stopped'){
    Write-Output ('Stopping Application Pool: {0}' -f $applicationPoolName)
    Stop-WebAppPool -Name $applicationPoolName
}
```

**Start application pool:**

```
if((Get-WebAppPoolState -Name $applicationPoolName).Value -ne 'Started'){
    Write-Output ('Starting Application Pool: {0}' -f $applicationPoolName)
    Start-WebAppPool -Name $applicationPoolName
}
```

**Permissions: You have to be a member of the "IIS Admins" group.**

Comment: Additional to this, your app pool can fail to start of it is still Stopping. The transition from Started to Stopped is not instant so you may need to add some timeouts/sleeps into your scripts to account for this.

Comment: This are two different scripts. First you run stop, then you make any work with web application, then you run second one.

Answer (score 23):

These days the IISAdminstration module has mostly superceded WebAdministration.

So if you're on Windows 10 / Server 2016, you can use [Get-IISAppPool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/get-iisapppool?view=windowsserver2022-ps) like this:

```
Import-Module IISAdministration
(Get-IISAppPool "name").Recycle()
```

Comment: THIS is correct!

Answer (score 10):

To stop an App Pool using PowerShell use

```
Stop-WebAppPool -Name YourAppPoolNameHere
```

And to start the App Pool

```
Start-WebAppPool -Name YourAppPoolNameHere
```

You will need the `WebAdministration` module installed so check you have it with this command

```
 Get-Module -ListAvailable
```

Comment: for all of them `Get-IISAppPool | Start-WebAppPool`

Answer (score 3):

You can stop and stop all application pools respectively using the following powershell script. The second line below elevates permissions. You could exclude this and just run as administrator.

**Stop all application pools script**

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) { Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PSCommandPath`"" -Verb RunAs; exit }

$AppPools=Get-ChildItem IIS:\AppPools | Where {$_.State -eq "Started"}

ForEach($AppPool in $AppPools)
{
 Stop-WebAppPool -name $AppPool.name
# Write-Output ('Stopping Application Pool: {0}' -f $AppPool.name)
}
```

**Start all application pools script**

```
  Import-Module WebAdministration

    if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) { Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PSCommandPath`"" -Verb RunAs; exit }

    $AppPools=Get-ChildItem IIS:\AppPools | Where {$_.State -eq "Stopped"}
    ForEach($AppPool in $AppPools)
    {
     Start-WebAppPool -name $AppPool.name
    # Write-Output ('Starting Application Pool: {0}' -f $AppPool.name)
    }
```

Comment: This worked great to ensure it's running as an admin, but you can replace everything else with: `Get-IISSite | Select-Object Name | Start-IISSite` and `Get-IISSite | Select-Object Name | Stop-IISSite` if you have access to `IISAdminstration`

Answer (score 3):

I use the following code in an Azure pipeline:

**Stop the pool:**

```
Import-Module -Name 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\WebAdministration\WebAdministration.psd1';

$AppPoolName = 'DefaultAppPool';
$AppPoolState = (Get-WebAppPoolState -Name $AppPoolName).Value;
$WasStarted = $false;
$Timeout = [System.TimeSpan]::FromMinutes(1);
$StopWatch = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch';
$StopWatch.Start();
# Possible status: "Starting", "Started", "Stopping", "Stopped" and "Unknown".
while ($AppPoolState -ne 'Stopped') {
  if ($AppPoolState -eq 'Started') {
    $WasStarted = $true;
    Stop-WebAppPool -Name $AppPoolName;
  }
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 2;
  if ($StopWatch.Elapsed -gt $Timeout) {
    throw New-Object -TypeName 'System.TimeoutException' -ArgumentList "Timeout of $($Timeout.TotalSeconds) seconds exceeded!";
  }
  $AppPoolState = (Get-WebAppPoolState -Name $AppPoolName).Value;
}
```

**Start the pool:**

```
Import-Module -Name 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\WebAdministration\WebAdministration.psd1';

$AppPoolName = 'DefaultAppPool';
$AppPoolState = (Get-WebAppPoolState -Name $AppPoolName).Value;
$WasStopped = $false;
$Timeout = [System.TimeSpan]::FromMinutes(1);
$StopWatch = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch';
$StopWatch.Start();
# Possible status: "Starting", "Started", "Stopping", "Stopped" and "Unknown".
while ($AppPoolState -ne 'Started') {
  if ($AppPoolState -eq 'Stopped') {
    $WasStopped = $true;
    Start-WebAppPool -Name $AppPoolName;
  }
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 2;
  if ($StopWatch.Elapsed -gt $Timeout) {
    throw New-Object -TypeName 'System.TimeoutException' -ArgumentList "Timeout of $($Timeout.TotalSeconds) seconds exceeded!";
  }
  $AppPoolState = (Get-WebAppPoolState -Name $AppPoolName).Value;
}
```

The variables `$WasStarted` and `$WasStopped` are extra information not used within this examples but could be used to determine whether an application pool should be restarted after the deployment of a new version is completed or not (because it was already stopped before).

Answer (score 2):

You have to import the `WebAdministration` module using [Import-Module](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=141553) and then you can use [Start-WebAppPool](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=268877) and [Stop-WebAppPool](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=268880)

Comment: That´s a permission problem. Try touse a administrator profile.

Comment: You can get an error if the application pool is stopped and you try to stop them. Execute this twice Stop-WebAppPool -Name "DefaultAppPool"

Comment: Since (PowerShell 3.0) you don´t need to import modules.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with something like this:

**Stopping the app pool:**

```
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: Stop App Pool
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          $applicationPoolName = '$(MySite)AppPool'

          if((Get-WebAppPoolState -Name $applicationPoolName).Value -ne 'Stopped')
          {
           Write-Output ('Stopping Application Pool: {0}' -f $applicationPoolName)
           Stop-WebAppPool -Name $applicationPoolName
           Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
          }
```

**Starting the app pool:**

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Start App Pool
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $applicationPoolName = '$(MySite)AppPool'

      if((Get-WebAppPoolState -Name $applicationPoolName).Value -ne 'Started')
      {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
        Write-Output ('Starting Application Pool: {0}' -f $applicationPoolName)
        Start-WebAppPool -Name $applicationPoolName
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

From microsoft doc. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadminstration/restart-webapppool?view=winserver2012-ps

Restart-WebAppPool recycles an application pool.
Then you don't have to think of a stop, wait, and start.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
```

For a specific running AppPool

```
$applicationPoolName = 'DefaultAppPool'
Get-ChildItem IIS:\AppPools | Where {$_.State -ne "Stopped" -and $_.name -eq $applicationPoolName} | Restart-WebAppPool
```

For all running AppPools

```
Get-ChildItem IIS:\AppPools | Where {$_.State -ne "Stopped"} | Restart-WebAppPool
```

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned by Mitch Pomery in the comments, the apppool does not stop instantly. Because of this, my CI script failes to copy files into the directory that was still being used by the apppool.
Instead, I reverted back to `appcmd` tool (which apparently waits for the apppool to actually stop), but still used `WebAdministration` module to check if the pool is running.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
if ((Get-WebAppPoolState -Name PCSServer).Value -ne 'Stopped'){ C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd stop apppool "PCSServer-WS" }
Expand-Archive -Path MBE.zip -DestinationPath $DEPLOY_PATH -Force
C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd start apppool "PCSServer-WS"
```