# How do I start and stop several IIS Applicationpools at once with a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, iis, automation, application-pool

I would like to create a PowerShell script that can Start and Stop several IIS Applicationpools at once.

I already found a similar article about this: [How to start and stop application pool in IIS using powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36599456/how-to-start-and-stop-application-pool-in-iis-using-powershell-script?newreg=132906ca4afe4b878c313ce5d08cc4ff)

But I would like to create a PowerShell script where I can define more than one IIS Application to stop them all at once through that script.

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: Loop through a string array, whose contents are the names of your AppPools, and stop them?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, how would I loop through only specific AppPools? For example only the ones that start with a certain name.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The link you provided already has a solution very close to what you need; look for "Stop all application pools script".

If you want to start/stop only some AppPools, put them in an array: replace `$AppPools=Get-ChildItem IIS:\AppPools | Where {$_.State -eq "Started"}` with `$AppPools=@('server1', 'server2', 'server3')`:

```
$AppPools=@('server1', 'server2', 'server3')

ForEach($AppPool in $AppPools) {
   Stop-WebAppPool -name $AppPool.name
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I would like to change that script to start / stop only app pool that name starts with or ends with certain characters. How would I define that in that script?

Comment: Well, you'd better learn a little bit of PowerShell before making this type of question, because all you need is to learn is the `Where-Object` command, and you can find this in Google.

Nonetheless, here's what you need to get just the apppools that start with "abc": replace `$AppPools=@('server1', 'server2', 'server3')` with `$AppPools=Get-ChildItem IIS:\AppPools | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "abc*"}` in the code I provided above.